# data and time in python

Tags: python, date, time, weekday

Code:

```
import datetime

intDay = datetime.date(year=2023, month=4, day=4).weekday()
days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
print(days[intDay])
```

I want both the week and the month to be printed on one line

Comment: This code give me this outpout (Tuesday)
I need like this (2023,04,04 Tuesday)

Answer (score 1):

**Code:**

```
import datetime

date = datetime.date(year=2023, month=4, day=4)
days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

print("{} {}".format(date.strftime("%Y,%m,%d"), days[date.weekday()])) #2023,04,04 Tuesday
```

To be more precise you don't need to create a `list` for ***weekdays*** you can directly obtained weekday using `strftime("%A")`.

**Code:**

```
import datetime
date = datetime.date(year=2023, month=4, day=4)
print(date.strftime("%Y,%m,%d %A")) #2023,04,04 Tuesday
```

Comment: you're welcome!! if you find the answer useful you can ✔️. @Homayoun

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `strftime` method to get your output. Look at this code:

```
 import datetime

 date = datetime.date(year=2023, month=4, day=4)
 intDay = date.weekday()
 days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]
 formatted_date = date.strftime("(%Y,%m,%d %A)")

 print(formatted_date)
```

Output:

```
(2023,04,04 Tuesday)
```